# Why can't I upload my project to Gitlab from VS Code?

Tags: git, visual-studio-code, deployment, gitlab, push

I tried to upload my gitlab project from the terminal in VS Code.

I entered the below code:

```
git remote add origin git@gitlab.com:username/my-first-api.git
git add .
git commit -m "comment"
git push -u origin master
```

But I got the error message:

> The authenticity of host 'gitlab.com (172.65.251.78)' can't be established.
> ECDSA key fingerprint is SHA256:HbW3g8zUjNSksFbqTiUWPWg2Bq1x8xdGUrliXFzSnUw.
> Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no/[fingerprint])? yes
> Warning: Permanently added 'gitlab.com,172.65.251.78' (ECDSA) to the list of known hosts.
> git@gitlab.com: Permission denied (publickey,keyboard-interactive).
> fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
> Please make sure you have the correct access rights
> and the repository exists.

I tried to watch tutorials on youtube but they don't seem to match the current Gitlab interface.

How do I upload my project?

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to connect using ssh, so you'll need to generate and add your ssh public key to your gitlab account:

1. Using ssh:

---

Link to use ssh from gitlab docs: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ssh/

To resume you can proceed with the part for generating your keys and then add the content of the .pub file using the gilab web interface in the user preferences:
[image]

2. Using https:

---

Gilab offers two differents links to access your repositories: by ssh and https, you could use the https option:

[image]

The link of the repository should be in the forms:

- https: https://gitlab.com/my-first-api.git
- ssh: git@gitlab.com:username/my-first-api.git